# Could not find generator active_scaffold_setup

Tags: activescaffold

Following this tutorial for setting up ActiveScaffold with Rails3:
http://vhochstein.wordpress.com/2010/08/28/setupactivescaffoldrails3/#comment-4

and, when I run the following command:

rails g active_scaffold_setup prototype

I get:

Could not find generator active_scaffold_setup.

Why is that? And, what should I do?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I got the command run after cloning the plugin from git and manuallly 
moving it to vendor/plugins in the Rails application folder.

Thanks all.